# Force Form Submit on Angular

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, forms

I am trying to submit a form which includes an angular form.

I just want to submit the form so that php can analyze it and download a csv file according to result generated.

I tried $('#form').submit() on my file as it contains jquery as well. However, no help.

There are other answers which sends data using $http. However, in my case i don't want to do that. Because PHP will force download a file and I am unable to do that as angular restrict form submit traditional way.

Any help would be appreciated...

Thank you!!!

Comment: Please include a code sample on both your angular and php.

Comment: Submitting a form has nothing to do with http. Submitting would mean you just press the button to invoke a method. And when using $http you are in control of the response and the resulting action. PHP won't force you anything, you can change what happens. If it downloads the file for you, what is the problem?